# Are there morphisms in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, functor

I have some GADT which represents a term in the lambda-calculus.

```
data Term a = 
      Var a
    | Lambda a (Term a)
    | Apply (Term a) (Term a)
```

What I want to do is to have a general interface for transformation on that type. It should have type signature similar to this:

```
(Term a -> Term a) -> Term a -> Term a
```

It's easy to write this function:

```
fmap' :: (Term a → Term a) → Term a → Term a 
fmap' f (Var v) = f (Var v)
fmap' f (Lambda v t) = Lambda v (fmap' f t)
fmap' f (Apply t1 t2) = Apply (fmap' f t1) (fmap' f t2)
```

So, my question is there some kind of general structure in haskell (or haskell library) to make this kind of transformations (similar to `Functor`, it should probably called morphism)?

Comment: So you're basically asking whether a type class like `class Morphism m where fmap' :: (m a → m a) → m a → m a` already exists (but perhaps with different names)?

Comment: @stakx, right, this is exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: I don't quite see what `fmap'`'s purpose is...  Isn't the simplest implementation of the given signature just `id`?

Comment: @Matthias, `id` only takes one argument, whereas `fmap'` is a binary operation. The important point appears to be that `fmap'` operates on and returns values of only one type; that's how it differs from e.g. `($)`.

Comment: @stakx: `fmap'` is unary, just like every other Haskell function.  `(m a → m a) → m a → m a` is the same as `(m a → m a) → (m a → m a)`, which is an instance of `id`'s type.

Comment: @Matthias, hmm... interesting. I didn't consider Mr Curry. Need to think about that. Still, it seems that `id` is not the *only* reasonable function with that signature.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For reference, here are the terms...

```
data Term a = 
      Var a
    | Lambda a (Term a)
    | Apply (Term a) (Term a)
```

(I note that the representation of variables is abstracted, which is often a good plan.)

...and here is the proposed function.

```
fmap' :: (Term a → Term a) → Term a → Term a 
fmap' f (Var v) = f (Var v)
fmap' f (Lambda v t) = Lambda v (fmap' f t)
fmap' f (Apply t1 t2) = Apply (fmap' f t1) (fmap' f t2)
```

What bothers me about this definition is that `f` is only ever applied to terms of form `(Var v)`, so you might as well implement *substitution*.

```
subst :: (a → Term a) → Term a → Term a 
subst f (Var v) = f v
subst f (Lambda v t) = Lambda v (subst f t)
subst f (Apply t1 t2) = Apply (subst f t1) (subst f t2)
```

If you took slightly more care to distinguish bound from free variables, you'd be able to make `Term` a `Monad` with substitution implementing `(>>=)`. In general, terms can have a `Functor` structure for renaming and a `Monad` structure for substitution. There's a lovely paper by [Bird and Paterson](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/richard.bird/online/BirdPaterson99DeBruijn.pdf) about that, but I digress.

Meanwhile, if you *do* want to act other than at variables, one general approach is to use general purpose traversal toolkits like uniplate, as augustss suggests. Another possibility, perhaps slightly more disciplined, is to work with the ‘fold’ for your type.

```
tmFold :: (x -> y) -> (x -> y -> y) -> (y -> y -> y) -> Term x -> y
tmFold v l a (Var x)       = v x
tmFold v l a (Lambda x t)  = l x (tmFold v l a t)
tmFold v l a (Apply t t')  = a (tmFold v l a t) (tmFold v l a t')
```

Here, `v`, `l` and `a` define an alternative *algebra* for your `Term`-forming operations, only acting on `y`, rather than `Term x`, explaining how to handle variables, lambdas and applications. You might choose `y` to be `m (Term x)` for some suitable monad `m` (e.g., threading an environment for the variables), rather than just `Term x` itself. Each subterm is processed to give a `y`, then the appropriate function is chosen to produce the `y` for the whole term. The fold captures the standard recursion pattern.

Ordinary first-order datatypes (and some well-behaved higher-order datatypes) can all be equipped with fold-operators. At a cost to readability, you can even write the fold operator once and for all.

```
data Fix f = In (f (Fix f))

fixFold :: Functor f => (f y -> y) -> Fix f -> y
fixFold g (In xf) = g (fmap (fixFold g) xf)

data TermF a t
  = VarF a
  | LambdaF a t
  | ApplyF t t

type Term a = Fix (TermF a)
```

Unlike your recursive `Term a`, this `TermF a t` explains how to make *one* layer of a term, with `t` elements in the subterm places. We get back the recursive `Term` structure by using the recursive `Fix` type. We lose a little cosmetically, in that each layer has an extra `In` wrapping it. We can define

```
var x      = In (VarF x)
lambda x t = In (LambdaF x t)
apply t t' = In (Apply x t t')
```

but we can't use those definitions in pattern matching. The payoff, though, is that we can use the generic `fixFold` at no extra cost. To compute a `y` from a term, we need only give a function of type

```
TermF a y -> y
```

which (just like `v`, `l`, and `a` above) explains how to handle any term whose subterms have already been processed to values of type `y`. By being explicit in types about what one layer consists of, we can tap into the general pattern of working layer by layer.

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at [the uniplate package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/uniplate).  It can do the kind of transformations you are talking about, but for an arbitrary data structure.

Comment: Specifically, transformations of this kind can be done with a uniplate function [named, appropriately enough, `transform`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/uniplate/1.6.1/doc/html/Data-Generics-Uniplate-Operations.html#v:transform). The docs even give an example very similar to the code in the question here!

Comment: Along the same lines, I'd recommend reading "A Pattern for Almost Compositional Functions": http://www.cse.chalmers.se/alumni/bringert/projects.html -- the compos operator described is, basically, the same as `transform`/`transformM` -- but how the paper gets there is quite straightforward.

Answer (score 4):

With the `fmap'` you quoted in the question, the transformation function `f` can only transform `Var` values to different lambda expressions. It cannot transform a `Lambda` or `Apply` into something else, since it's hardcoded in the `fmap'` function that these constructors stay the same.

Your `fmap'` can for example transform `Var 1` into `Lambda 1 (Var 1)`, but not the other way around.
Is this really your intention?

If `fmap'` should allow arbitrary transformations, you end up with this:

```
fmap' :: (Term a → Term a) → Term a → Term a 
fmap' f t = f t
```

This is the same as `$`.

(If, on the other hand, `fmap'` should only be allowed to change the values in the expression, without changing its structure at all, you would be back at the usual `fmap`.)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I don't have an answer to your actual question, though I do have some ideas that might be useful to you, not sure.

That seems to me to be less general than it might be, I'd expect you to use something like:

```
fmap' :: (Term a → Term a) → Term a → Term a 
fmap' f (Var v) = f $ Var v
fmap' f (Lambda v t) = f $ Lambda v (fmap' f t)
fmap' f (Apply t1 t2) = f $ Apply (fmap' f t1) (fmap' f t2)
```

which still allows you the same functionality, you just do pattern matching within f itself. I think this function can be used to things like evaluation of your lambda calculus (though, there's some state you need to bring around with you).

Something that might be more useful in the future for you might be:

```
fmapM :: Monad m => (Term a -> m (Term a)) -> Term a -> m (Term a)
fmapM f (Var v)         = f (Var v)
fmapM f (Lambda v t)    = do
    t' <-fmapM f t
    f (Lambda v t')
fmapM f (Apply t1 t2)   = do
    t1' <- fmapM f t1
    t2' <- fmapM f t2
    f (Apply t1' t2')
```

Which you can then use later with a State monad to keep track of bindings from lambdas. Also this function is the same as the one above when you use the Identity monad, you could write a simple function taking f :: (Term a -> Term a) and use fmap' f = fmapM (f.(return :: -> Identity a)).

Let me know if this is helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

You may find the [unbound](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unbound) package useful, especially the [substs](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/unbound/0.2.5/doc/html/Unbound-LocallyNameless-Subst.html#t%3aSubst) function.